# Calculate amount of figures

Tags: tables, floats, counters

Is there way to automatically calculate amount of figures, tables and appendices? 
I found a way to see what pages have figures([Automatically determine numbers of pages with figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202676/automatically-determine-numbers-of-pages-with-figures) ), but how to calculate the amount.

Comment: The figures counter shoved in caption gives amount of figures in section or chapter or whole document (depend, how you determine `\thefigure`, which determine caption number).

Comment: So if want add text like " in the document there is \thefigure(lastfigure) figures" ?

Comment: Hm, this is not so simple. As I said, depends on how it is defined (if the counter `figure` is reset at each section or chapter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of figures etc. can be retrieved with the `totcount` package, however, the resetting feature of `chapter` counters will result in wrong values.

Best is the usage of the `xassoccnt` and `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` which combines `total counter` features with the concept of `associated` counters, the later are stepped each time a driver counter, say `figure` is stepped as well, but are **not** reset. (Manual change is not tracked, of course!)

Using total counters has the advantage that their value is known in advance (after the first run) and can be used right at the start of the document then to do calculation or a specific setup etc.

Two compilation runs are needed, adding/removing a figure/table/chapter etc. will change the number of course and another run is necessary to get the `total counter value` in line again.

Normally, associated counters should be declared in the preamble already, but the appendix chapters should be counted only, not all chapters, so use `\AddAssociatedCounters` in place, i.e. right from the position where the feature is needed.

In the example, I assumed appendix chapters, if sections are used, then replace `\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}` with `\AddAssociatedCounters{section}{appendixsections}` and change the counter name to `appendixsections`.

Please note that `page` is an unreliable counter in conjunction with `xassoccnt`.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}
\begin{document}

There are \TotalValue{totalfigures} figures in this document

There are \TotalValue{totaltables} tables in this document

There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters in this document


\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}


\chapter{Second}


\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}


\appendix

\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}

\chapter{Foo Appendix}
\chapter{FooBar Appendix}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]