# Total pages number warning and miscalculated

Tags: counters, totalcount, xassoccnt

The question is a follow-up to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295909/92620).

I think that the document is suppsed to display 9 instead of 8 ? also the current position of `\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}` (instead of the preamble whic will give wrong number by the way) generate a warning:

> Warning: An accidental(?) addition of associated counter(s) without * DeclareAssociatedCounters was detected for * the driver counter "chapter" and following driven counters: * --- appendixchapters ---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}

\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters in this document

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\appendix

\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}

\chapter{Foo Appendix}
\chapter{FooBar Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a warning, nothing more or less. It's better to use `\DeclareAssociatedCounters` right from the start for all relevant counters! The page counter is an unreliable friend, actually. (And I am the author of `xassoccnt`)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but in this case we cant right ? otherwise appendixchapters final value would be 4 instead of 2. talking about the wrong total number of pages what did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `page` counter is very tricky, also for `xassoccnt` (yet).

What is working for basically any other counter causes troubles with `page`, i.e. the counter value is off by one usually.

Another issue is `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` starts at `-1` -- I will change this in a new version of `xassoccnt` in order to make it freely adjustable with some option key value.

For the moment, the best fix is to use `\addtocounter{xassoccnt@total@totalpages}{1}`. (`xassoccnt@total@totalpages` is the internal name of this counter)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocounter{xassoccnt@total@totalpages}{1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters in this document

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\appendix

\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}

\chapter{Foo Appendix}
\chapter{FooBar Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Also use `AddAssociatedCounters` also as a remedy only, it's possible to define the counters in the beginning already, suspend them and resume them accordingly:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}

\SuspendCounters{appendixchapters}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocounter{xassoccnt@total@totalpages}{1}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters in this document

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\appendix

\ResumeSuspendedCounters{appendixchapters}

\chapter{Foo Appendix}
\chapter{FooBar Appendix}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{book}
%compile twice

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}
\NewDocumentCounter{realpages}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\usepackage{everyshi}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{realpages}%
}
\EveryShipout{%
  \stepcounter{realpages}%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \setcounter{xassoccnt@total@totalpages}{\value{realpages}}%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{xassoccnt@total@totalpages}{\number\value{realpages}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

There are \TotalValue{totalfigures} figures in this document

There are \TotalValue{totaltables} tables in this document

There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters in this document

There are \TotalValue{totalpages} pages in this document
\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}


\chapter{Second}


\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure foo \thefigure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}


\appendix

\AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}

\chapter{Foo Appendix}
\chapter{FooBar Appendix}



\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table foo \thetable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, and nice to know the package will be updated/improved in the future :)

Comment: @SAM: Let's say `updated` ;-)

Comment: it seems the solution only fix the issue in that specific case, please look at http://pastebin.com/VETc1eiW instead of 10 we got 9, the value added to the counter must be 2...we are in a loop?

Comment: @SAM: As I said: page is a tricky counter.

Comment: @SAM: This is nothing that can be solved without severe hacking or very manipulative methods

Comment: most important for now we have diagnosed this issue.

Comment: @SAM: See the update, please

Comment: @Christian_Hupfer it seems to work good this time even when i added some other tabs and indices it works, hope it aa generic solution.